# Appositive with “no”

Tags: appositives

Given the statements "Jennifer is a smart student" and "[this] Jennifer doesn’t exist", I am trying to write a single sentence that explains both these things.  I have two ideas for how to write it:

1. “There’s no Jennifer, a smart student”.
2. ”There’s no Jennifer, no smart student”.

I think sentence 2 is correct because the first statement says "Jennifer is a smart student", so no Jennifer means no smart student, but I'm not sure if the second "no" is needed, so I think it *could* be sentence 1 if I'm wrong.

Which is actually correct?  Or are both wrong?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to say. Your second sentence makes a bit of sense, but your first sentence is impenetrable.

Comment: @Colin Fine I was just trying to ask why the sentence 1 is impenetrable. Sorry if it’s ill-written.

Comment: @Gabriel Please edit the question to explain what it is you are trying to say? Is it that there is nobody called Jennifer? That there are no smart students? Both?

Comment: @DJClayworth Jennifer and a smart student are the same person.

Comment: Please edit the information into the question.

Comment: I've edited the question a bit, I think this rewrite properly conveys Gabriel's intent.  Please feel free to edit it further or let us know in the comments here if my edit went too far.

Comment: @RichardWinters Thank you for revising.

Comment: If Jennifer doesn't exist, how can she be a smart student? Please explain what you are trying to say here.

Comment: Jennifer, a smart student, is not in this class. That's an appositive.

Comment: @DJClayworth Yes, that’s what I’m asking.

Comment: Please explain 1) who is Jennifer 2) why is she considered smart 3) how she can be smart if she doesn't exist?

Comment: 1. Jennifer is a smart student. 2. Because she was born this way. 3. That’s what I’m asking.

Comment: @DJClayworth Please forgive me that I’m a beginner in English, so I have no good English-writing ability to explain clearly.

Comment: @Gabriel Both your sentences are statements that Jennifer is a smart student. You seem to want to write that Jennifer is a smart student. But then you say you are "asking if Jennifer is a smart student". That doesn't make sense. I think you are just going about this all wrong. If you are learning English, write simpler sentences and don't use appositives.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of [apposition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/apposition):

"Jennifer, a smart student, doesn't exist"

The noun phrase "a smart student" tells us a little bit more about "Jennifer". The rest of the sentence tells us that Jennifer doesn't exist.

If you needed to include the word "no" in the sentence, you could write:

"There is no student, Jennifer, smart or otherwise".

I can't think of a way to include "no Jennifer" that sounds natural to me. Given that Jennifer doesn't exist, we can't say whether she was smart or not.

Comment: Thank you, but I want to use “no Jennifer” and a corresponding apposition.

Comment: Why do you want to use both "no Jennifer" and apposition? It's going to be problematic and hard to understand. Is this for some sort of exercise?

Answer (score 1):

It is odd to use a bare appositive in a sentence denying the existence of the noun.

> Arthur, king of the Britons, never existed.

Well, if he never existed, was he really king of the Britons?  Do existing unicorns exist?

Better, I think, to put an explanation in the appositive.

> Arthur, legendary king of the Britons, never existed.

Answer (score 1):

You could say

> There is no Jennifer who is a smart student.

This implies that there is another Jennifer who is *not* a smart student!

Or maybe

> There is no smart student Jennifer.

although that might be better written as

> There is no "smart student, Jennifer".

and I could only see using it in response to a question like "Hey, do you know that smart student, Jennifer?"